# Custom tick labelling with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a bit puzzled with D3js automatic axis tick labelling.
I would like to show a label for each day, and only show ticks for every hour of the day. Below is a screenshot of my axis.
How can I achieve this with D3.js ?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format  multiFormat function

Comment: Thanks, I will try to adapt this function

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have coded using https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format multiFormat function

```
function multiFormat(date) {
    var formatHour = d3.timeFormat(""), formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%Y") ;
    return ( d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour : formatDay)(date);
};

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks( d3.timeHour.every(1) )
    .tickFormat( multiFormat );
```

to get this
[image]